# Socket.read() return nothing and doesn't throw exception when closed in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception, tcpclient

I have a Android code that send and receive data from a TCP socket. It works fine, but, when the socket is suddenly closed (disconnection from wi-fi, for example), i don't get any error, both for reading and for writing.
In some devices, An exception is thrown in read thread, but in other devices (Note 4) no exception is thrown, and the app can't detect wheter the socket is closed or not.

The write code is bellow

```
try {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    writer.write(msg);
    writer.flush();
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The read Thread:

```
try {

    int bytesRead;
    String print = new String();
    print = "";
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();

    while (socket.isConnected()) {
        bytesRead = is.read();
        if (bytesRead != -1) {
            print += (char) bytesRead;
            if (bytesRead == ']') {
                final String toprint = new String(print);
                try{
                ((socketListener) Ui).onSocketListen(ip,toprint);
                }catch(NullPointerException ex){

                }
                print = "";
            }
        } else {
            socket.close();
            socket = new Socket();
            break;
        }

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    socket = new Socket();
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> the app can't detect wheter the socket is closed or not

The socket *isn't* closed. The connection is temporarily interrupted, but TCP is designed to survive that. Unless you have pending sends you won't detect a network interruption.

You can set a read timeout with `Socket.setSoTimeout()`, and when you catch the resulting `SocketTimeoutException` make a decision somehow on whether you're going to try again or give up.

Comment: About the pending sends, even if I try to send data during the interruption, the write function does not throw exception too. About the 'Socket,setSoTimeout()', i've tried ,but 'read()' function kept not detecting the interruption after the 'SocketTimeoutException', so i think i'll need to implement some kind of heartbeat in the server side, correct?

Comment: It *can't* detect the interruption. All you have is the fact that it timed out. You have to decide what that means. Re the writes, the failure isn't immediate: TCP has to time out the retries. It may take several sends. You can use a heartbeat, but I've never used one, and e.g. RMI and CORBA don't either, or HttpURLConnection, so it isn't necessary.